# How to show tweets with twitter api on express.js with node.js?

Tags: node.js, express, twitter

I'm trying to show twits on client side. Already try with express-generator but it does not work. 
I can see them in the console, but I can not get them out there and show them in the front. I'm sure it should be simple.
please, help!
thanks

server.js

```
const http = require('http')
const port = 5004;
const app = require('./app')
const mongoConnection = require('./db/config/mongoConnection')

http
   .createServer()
   .on('request', app)
   .on('error', function(error){
    switch (error.code){
     case 'EADDRINUSE':
      console.log('error')
     break;
     case 'EACCES':
     console.log('error de permisos')
     break;
     default:
     throw error;
    }
 })
.listen(port)
```

app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const twitsModel = require('./db/models/twits')
const controller = require('./controller')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const twitter = require('twitter'); 
const config = require('./config') 
const client = new twitter(config); 

const params = {
     q: 'apple', count: 3 
}

const app = express()
.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))
.use(bodyParser.json())


client.get('search/tweets', params, function(error, tweets, response){
    console.log(tweets)
})
.use(express.static('./public')) // -----> it does not work


module.exports = app
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main file is usually called `server.js` *or* `app.js`. It doesn't make much sense to have both. In your case, it's simpler to keep the code in one file.

```
const twitsModel = require('./db/models/twits')
const controller = require('./controller')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const twitter = require('twitter'); 
const config = require('./config') 
const client = new twitter(config); 
const http = require('http')
const port = 5004;
const mongoConnection = require('./db/config/mongoConnection')

function sendTweet(req, res) {
  const params = {
     q: 'apple', count: 3 
  } 

 client.get('search/tweets', params, function(error, tweets, response){
    if(error) {
       console.log("Error getting tweets");
       return;
    }
    console.log(tweets);
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
    res.end(JSON.stringify(tweets)); // This line sends the tweets to the client making the http request.
    });
});


http.createServer(sendTweet).listen(port)
```

Comment: thanks! just try it but it's still failing, says "First argument must be a string or Buffer" any clue?

Comment: `tweets` is an object, and `res` is not an object mode stream, so do `res.end(JSON.stringify(tweets))`